# Chrome Dev Tools not displaying dynamic DOM updates

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Can someone please tell me why I cannot view updates made to the text box in the highlighted value field on the input field?

The textbox has 'new1234' but Chrome Dev Tools say it is 'Old123'.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="testInput" type="text" value="Old123" />
</body>
<script>
    document.getElementById('testInput').value = 'New1234';
</script>
</html>
```

Here is the screen shot:
[image]

```js
document.getElementById('testInput').value = 'New1234';
```

```html
<input id="testInput" type="text" value="Old123" />
```

Comment: Had the same issue, for my part, I had a duplicate id.

Answer (score 1):

The `.value` property in Javascript references a property on the `HTMLElement` *object* that Javascript can interface with. Element property values do not necessarily correspond with the *attributes* that you can see in the browser's inspector tools. You *can* change an element's attribute if you wish, though, via `setAttribute`.

(`Inspect` the following snippets with your browser tools:)

```js
document.getElementById('testInput').setAttribute('value', 'New1234');
```

```html
<input id="testInput" type="text" value="Old123" />
```

But, while this *works*, it's generally better to assign to the plain Javascript property of the element, rather than change the HTML itself.

Certain property changes *do* change the attributes, such as when you set the `id` or `className` of an element:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('testInput');
element.id = 'foo';
element.className = 'bar';
```

```html
<input id="testInput" type="text" value="Old123" />
```

But assigning to `.value` is not one of those which change the HTML attributes as well.